# How do I use MigrationBuilder DeleteData to delete all rows during a migration?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.deletedata?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_DeleteData_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_String_) is not very helpful - just a list of function signatures, of which the simplest is:

> public virtual OperationBuilder DeleteData (string table, string keyColumn, object keyValue, string schema = null);

I am fairly sure I can work out what goes in table, keyColumn and schema, but what value should I put in keyValue if I want to delete all rows?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

doesn't look like the DeleteData operations are designed to allow for a delete everything in the table operation.  EF uses the keyColumn and keyValue to determine what to delete, i.e. where keyColumn = keyValue.  I would recommend using something like this:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("DELETE FROM [table]", true);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Operations/DeleteDataOperation.cs

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/MigrationBuilder.cs  (about line 1400)

Comment: Why the second argument `suppressTransaction` should be `true`?

Comment: [MigrationStatement.SuppressTransaction Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.sql.migrationstatement.suppresstransaction?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) *Gets or sets a value indicating whether this statement should be performed outside of the transaction scope that is used to make the migration process transactional. If set to true, this operation will not be rolled back if the migration process fails.*

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I agree that the documentation would be more helpful with examples.  Here's how I deleted mutliple rows without a lot of repetitive statments:

```
var keyValues = new Object[] {

    new Guid("3DED1B8E-88D7-4C4E-9A02-3C11FF210EA9"),
    new Guid("E0DFFCFB-6479-49BA-BCEE-13243A95FAC8"),
    new Guid("D953AC1E-674B-4EA9-9C1F-572B454133ED"),
    new Guid("06ad3c30-2b01-473c-8617-9966fae63739"),
}; 
migrationBuilder.DeleteData(
    table: "ValidOperationTypes",
    keyColumn: "Id",
    keyColumnType: "Guid",
    keyValues: keyValues);
```